# When files[] is opened more than once, previous uploads are erased

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, file-upload

I am creating and using a custom image uploader within my form which is submitted via ajax - everything works perfect.

I am allowing users to upload multiple images e.g:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" class="files-data" id="upload_images" multiple="">
```

The problem that I am facing, is that when a user clicks the "Image Upload Button" multiple times, each time the input (the array of previously uploaded images) is reset.

So if a user uploads 3 images, great - that works fine. But if they decide to open the file upload again and upload another image or two, the original 3 files are gone.

I am not looking for a plugin to do this, and I know that this can be done from other image uploaders I have seen.

Do you know how I can maintain previously uploaded images when the multiple input field is opened more than once?

Thank-you for any help.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the upload but in what you do with the data after that. Can you share that code?

Comment: Gone, you mean erased in server? Or got replaced?or...

Comment: No, what I mean is with a default "multiple file upload", each time the file uploader opens, whatever has previously been uploaded is erased.What I am working on right now is figuring out how to push each uploaded image into an array and storing it so nothing is lost in the case a user opens the file uploader multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of HTML. You need to manage those uploaded files via javascript/jQuery in order to maintain the user selection and for which the plugins you are trying to escape from will do that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by looping through the uploaded images and storing them into an array each time a new file is uploaded. My problem was that I was doing something completely different, and just overriding the files each time the user uploads more files.

Some common sense, and sitting here to think for a while helped me solve this one :)

```
MyForm = {}; // empty array
MyForm.userUploads = []; // empty object


    $('.add-listing-photos input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {

        // Get the files.
        var files = $(this)[0].files;

        // For each file, append it onto the end of our array.
        for( var key in files ) {
            if( typeof( files[key] ) === 'object' ) {
                MyForm.userUploads.push( files[key] );
            }
        }

        console.log(MyForm.userUploads);

    });
```

And then sent this through my ajax request.